# Different count of documents in elastic search for the same query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have incomprehensible behavior with elasticsearch (I use elasticsearch 5.2). I have index with ~5m documents. I try to search something. For example, I use this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

If I execute query several times, I get the different count of documents in hits.total. The different is 1 document (first time I have 5032511 docs, another time: 5032510)

The same situation, if I execute count query (first time I have 5032511 docs, another time: 5032510)

Does anybody know why this happens? And what I need to do to get the same count each time, when I execute query?

P.S. I use number_of_shards: 5, number_of_replicas: 1 for this index. Maybe this important to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this is active index and there's some clients writing to it, most probable rootcase is long index refresh (which is kinda often-used optimisation for large indices). Try executing [refresh query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) before counting. But beware, it can be sort of expensive for high-loaded indices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, this is not active index right now. We don't write anything new in this index for a few months. So this is not problem of indexing :(